# SFDX Retrive package

Tags: salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

I am trying to retrieve package with name containing spaces for example "Hello World", i have tried using single quotes as mentioned by salesforce
`sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -u test -p 'Hello World' -s -r`

Here is the error message I am getting -

> C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Generally speaking, the more details you include, the better. In this particular case, it sounds like you sohuld be getting an error message. If you are, you should [edit] your question to include the full text of the error message **verbatim**. The error might not make sense to you, but it can help the more experienced eyes here narrow down the list of potential problems.

Comment: What happens when you type `sfdx` into your terminal?

Comment: Thanks@ZackWalton. I have salesforce cli installed in my system and when i enter sfdx , it is showing the help topics as expected.

Comment: Here is the workaround guys - I am having the issue ( mentioned in the question ) in gitbash , but i am able to retrieve the package in cmd using double quotes. sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -u test -p 'Hello World' -s -r